# Help in polynomial question

Tags: polynomials

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are zeroes of $ax^2 + bx -c$, find $\alpha^2/\beta + \beta^2/\alpha$.
Here is what I did:- (I will use a for $\alpha$, b for $\beta$)

1. By LCM, we need to find $a^3 + b^3/ab$.
2. $a^3 + b^3 = (a+b)^3 - 3ab(a+b)$
   $ = -b^3/a^3- 3c/a(-b/a) = 3abc-b^3/a^3.$

Now bringing denominator and simplifying we get, $3abc-b^3/a^2c$.
But the answer is $b^3 + 3abc/a^2c$.

Comment: Here $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of given polynomial
So use the concept that in this case
$\alpha+\beta=\frac{b}{a}$ and $\alpha\beta=-\frac{c}{a}$ then try to find out what you want.....

Comment: The constant term is $\color{red}-c$.

Comment: @Bernard Oh thank you.